# Convert struct to query Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, struct

Wondering if anyone can assist

I am utilizing some code from [RIAForge](http://www.riaforge.org) which integrates with the Last.fm api...

One of the methods outputs as a struct, but I would like to modify the code so it outputs as an array, am unsure of how to do this..

Currently the code is like this

```
<cfscript>
 var args = StructNew();
 var returnStruct = StructNew();
 var results = "";
 var i = 0;


 args['playlistURL'] = arguments.playlistURL;

 results = super.callMethod('playlist.fetch', args).playlist;


 returnStruct['title'] = results[':title'];
 returnStruct['annotation'] = results[':annotation'];
 returnStruct['creator'] = results[':creator'];
 returnStruct['date'] = results[':date'];


 if(StructKeyExists(results, ':trackList') AND StructKeyExists(results[':trackList'], ':track')){
 results = super.ensureArray(results[':trackList'][':track']);

 returnStruct['tracks'] = QueryNew('album,creator,duration,identifier,image,info,title');

 for(i=1; i LTE ArrayLen(results); i=i+1){
 QueryAddRow(returnStruct.tracks);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'album', results[i].album);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'creator', results[i].creator);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'duration', results[i].duration);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'identifier', results[i].identifier);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'image', results[i].image);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'info', results[i].info);
 QuerySetCell(returnStruct.tracks, 'title', results[i].title);
 }
}
 return returnStruct;
```

Am just wondering if there is a coldfusion method that allows me to convert the returnStruct into a query..

Many thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you modify the method itself to return query (though I prefer arrays)?

Comment: Just for cleanliness sake, if you're returning a Query, you might want to call the return variable "returnQuery" instead of "returnStruct". That's bound to throw someone when they look back at this.

Answer (score 5):

In CF 10 and Railo 4, you can use the [QueryNew() function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f94.html) if you have an array of structs that you want to convert to a query.

Usage: `QueryNew(columnList, columnTypeList, arrayOfStructs)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have moved on from coldfusion for now, but thanks regardless.

Answer (score 2):

CFLIB.org is your friend

[QueryToArrayOfStructures](http://www.cflib.org/udf/QueryToArrayOfStructures)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it by hand by looping over your results and placing in an Array of Arrays. If, you want to convert your struct to a query there are functions at http://www.cflib.org that are ready to go.

```
var returnArray = []; /* or arrayNew(1) if not on Railo or CF9 */

/* ACF9 or Railo Style */
arrayAppend(returnArray, [results[':title'],results[':annotation'],results[':creator'],results[':date'] ]);

/* ACF8 and earlier */
arrayAppend( returnArray, arrayNew(1) ]);
arrayAppend( returnArray[ arrayLen(returnArray) ], results[':title'] ]);
arrayAppend( returnArray[ arrayLen(returnArray) ], results[':annotation'] ]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response...when i try the code arrayAppend(returnArray, [results[':title'],results[':annotation'],results[':creator'],results[':date'] ]; I get the error message "Invalid token ;". Thanks

Comment: If your not on CF9 or Railo, you'll need to do the code in /* ACF8 and earlier */

Comment: Had the same issue with that code...had to remove an extra ']' from the end of the function line. Will have a look into this..thanks